# how to make html table rows equal in php

Tags: php, css, html-table

[image: picture are example only]

data is from my database they are not same value of data. and my html display are not good to view, is there any way to create empty td?

```
  <?php while($team= mysqli_fetch_assoc($team_set)){ ?>

      <td><?php echo htmlentities($team['tname']); ?></td>

  

   <?php while($grade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grade_set)){ ?>
     <td><?php echo htmlentities($grade['points']); ?></td>
  <?php } mysqli_free_result($grade_set);  ?>


        <td><?php echo htmlentities($team['sum']); ?></td>

 <?php } mysqli_free_result($team_set);  ?>
```

Comment: Can the data be `join`ed from your query? That way it ensures the same amount of rows

Comment: "*is there any way to create empty td?*" When no value you can create just `<td>&nbsp;</td>`. To make them equal (in width) use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I would reorganize the structure of the middle part, i.e. this part of your code:

```
<?php while($grade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grade_set)){ ?>
   <td><?php echo htmlentities($grade['points']); ?></td>
<?php } mysqli_free_result($grade_set);  ?>
```

Here *every* entry is put into its own table cell, creating what you describe in your question (different amount of cells in each row). I would instead put all these entries into *one*  cell:

```
<td class="points_cell">
  <?php while($grade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grade_set)){ ?>
     <span class="points"><?php echo htmlentities($grade['points']); ?></span>
  <?php } mysqli_free_result($grade_set);  ?>
</td>
```

As you can see, I wrapped the single entries into `span` tags  with a class (`.points`) and created and applied the class `.points_cell` to the cell that wraps them. For these two classes you can create CSS rules similar to this:

```
.points_cell {
   white-space: nowrap;
} 
.points {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

`white-space: nowrap;` on `.points_cell` makes sure the `.points` spans are not put *below* each other, but *in one line*. The side padding in `.points` creates sufficient distance between the entries - this value can of course be adjusted as needed.

You could also create CSS `borders` (left and right) or alternating background colors for those span elements if you want to set them apart in a more obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

To output table cells using only PHP, you'd need to pre-loop your arrays, find the max in any row, then loop again that many times when you actually display.

Here I'm ls using a temporary array to hold the results so you don't need to call the database twice. I made some assumptions about your SQL result set, so you may need to modify it slightly.

```
   <?php
     // Call database, pre-looping result set
     $max = 1;
     $table_arr = array();

     while( $team = mysqli_fetch_assoc($team_set) ){
        $tmp = array();
        while( $grade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grade_set) ){
          $tmp[] = $grade['points'];
        }
        mysqli_free_result($grade_set);
        
       // Store results for later use
        $table_arr[] = array(
           'tname'   => $team['tname'],
           'sum'     => $team['sum '],
           'points'  => $tmp,
        );
        // Get max cells in any result set
        $max = max( $max, count($tmp) );
     }
     mysqli_free_result($team_set);
   ?>

<?php
  // Loop $table_array to actually output things
  foreach ($table_array as $team) {
 ?>
   <td><?php echo htmlentities($team['tname']); ?></td>

  <?php
    // loop $max times, output points if present else empty cell
    for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++) {
      $points = isset( $team['points'][ $x ] ) ? $team['points'][ $x ] : '&nbsp;';
  ?>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($points); ?></td>
  <?php } ?>

    <td><?php echo htmlentities($team['sum']); ?></td>

<?php } ?>
```